# Populating a Textbox with a Text File but it always adds a blank first line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a file containing text and I can get it to populate a textbox on page load but it always adds a blank first line. Any ideas? I've tried skipping the first line in the array in case it was blank (both 0 and 1) but 0 does nothing and 1 skips the first line in the text file.

I've also tried to set the textbox to `null` and `""` first in case it was appending to the textbox in some way.

```
//Populating the contents box
string[] str = null;
if (File.Exists(docPath + prefix + libIDPath + "\\" + oldFileName))
{
    str = File.ReadAllLines(docPath + prefix + libIDPath + "\\" + oldFileName);
    //str = str.Skip(0).ToArray();
    //FDContentsBox.Text = null;
}
foreach (string s in str)
{
            FDContentsBox.Text = FDContentsBox.Text + "\n" + s;
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to read the file in a "by line fashion"? In the shown code it would be sufficient to just read the file completely (File.ReadAllText) and add it to FDContentsBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, there is no need to read all lines nor a foreach loop

```
var filePath = docPath + prefix + libIDPath + "\\" + oldFileName;
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    FDContentsBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner and it is working, thanks

Comment: @TimEdwards Also consider using `Path.Join` to make path concatenation much easier.

Answer (score 2):

In your `foreach` you are appending the "\n" before appending the string itself.  Try

`FDContentsBox.Text = FDContentsBox.Text + s + "\n";`

instead.